# iPhone - Navigation bar Back button item is not responding

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem

I have a fullscreen modalView called like this:

```
PreferencesController *nextWindow = [[[PreferencesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Preferences" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController* navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Then from this modalView I push another view :

```
    MyController *nextWindow = [[[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tmp" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextWindow animated:YES];
```

In this new controller, I have this viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Borders";
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

The leftBarButtonItem is not active, I mean touching it does not highlight it nor does it go back to the previous view.

My views are displayed fullScreen, with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` called at the application initialisation.

The navigationBar frame is 0,0,320,44.
The navigationBar superview frame is 0,0,320,480.
The viewController view frame is 0,0,320,436.

I've tried to call in viewDidLoad `self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;` without effect.

What happens?

**EDIT :**
My self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is NIL.
self.navigationController.navigationItem is not NIL

Comment: What other code do you have going on in your viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Wayne Hartman : That's the whole code.

Comment: Does this only happen for this particular view controller (MyController) or is it the same behaviour with any other view controller pushed onto the navigation controller's stack from this point in your app? I mean the code you posted looks ok, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @hennes : It's the only viewController I call.

Comment: So your xib is called tmp.xib? and in IB its class is set as MyController?

Comment: @Oliver Ok, but maybe you can try pushing a plain view controller ([[UIViewController alloc] init]) to see if the problem is with your custom view controller. In addition can you check if the problem still exists when you show the navigation bar before pushing the view controller?

Comment: @hennes : I tried both solutions, that does not change anything

Comment: @oliver what are you using for dismiss your view with left button click.is it popmodelviewcontroller?

Comment: @Oliver now in my apps I am also Using same thing and my code working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was that the first view was called from the overlay, and not from the picker.
Keeping a reference to the Picker into the overlay, and calling the view from it solves the problem:

From the overlay:

```
[self.picker presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

works

instead of:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this sort of unresponsiveness happens to me, it is always because of framing issues. i.e. the superview of the NavigationController is smaller than the NavigationController's view. I know you say that everything is set to full screen, but I would verify that everything is actually full screen by turning "clipsSubviews" on for each view in the hierarchy.

Comment: I tried clip subview and also tried forcing self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; self.navigationController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; in viewDidLoad, and that does not change the problem.

Comment: the navigationBar frame is 0,0,320,44 and the navigationBar superview frame is 0,0,320,480. The controlelrsview frame is 0,0,320,436

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, I'm not sure why this works, but instead of doing:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:nil
                                 action:nil] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

I replaced the second line with

```
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

That works for me.

Comment: thank you, but I never create this button. It is auto generated by the NavigationController. So I can't apply your solution in that case.

Comment: event if I force in viewDidLoad self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                                                  target:nil
                                                                                                  action:nil] autorelease]; Nothing changes and the button name does not change too.

Comment: @Oliver Are you sure you are referencing the correct leftBarButtonItem ? I think it's the previous controller that sets the action of the leftBarButtonItem, so if you have controllers 1 & 2, then setting the back button for 2 has to be done in 1.

Comment: @steamba : I do not set anything. The button is automatically set by the pushViewController call.